# How can a client know if it is already subscribed to a MQTT topic?

Tags: kotlin, mqtt, aws-iot

I'm subscribing to a MQTT Topic(in my case it is app unique user id).I'm using AWS IOT core services for subscription.Whenever home screen opens up and I got connected callback from awsConnectClient,I make the call for subscription. Now what is happening if app gets open up three times It subscribed to the same topic 3 time.Now whenever any message publish to that topic.It received by app 3 times.

Now what I want to do that I want to know that if this userId is already subscribed from this device I would not make a call for subscription again from same device.

One approach could be If I save in my app that I had already subscribed to this topic and do not make the call for subscription again. but I doubt if this approach could be correct for all scenarios.Could it be possible that we could drive this logic from the server end only, if any aws iot api could give me that this is already subscribed.

```
fun connectClick() {
    Log.d(TAG, "clientId = $clientId")

    try {
        mqttManager.connect(clientKeyStore) { status, throwable ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Status = " + status.toString())
            var formattedStatus = String.format(getString(R.string.status_msg),status.toString())

            if (status == AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback.AWSIotMqttClientStatus.Connected) {
                Log.i(TAG, " subscribed to - " + VoiceXPreference(this).rosterName)
                unsubscribe()
                subscribeClick(VoiceXPreference(this).rosterName)
            }
            runOnUiThread {
                tv_iot_status.text = formattedStatus
                if (throwable != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Connection error.", throwable)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Connection error.", e)
    }

}
```

Above is my subscription code.Although I'm always unsubscribing before subscribing but this is not working for me.

Following is my initClient call which makes the connection request. I have added the if check if mqttManager is already initialised first disconnect and then make connect request. Although I have put initRequest inside onCreate() call back of app screen which calls only once when the app opens up. I have checked the logs it is being called only once.

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this, object : Callback<UserStateDetails> {
            override fun onResult(result: UserStateDetails) {
                Log.i(TAG,"connect request called");
                if(mqttManager != null){
                    mqttManager?.disconnect()
                }
                initIoTClient()
            }

            override fun onError(e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onError: ", e)
            }
        })
```

Following is my subscribe code snippet which is subscribing to unique userId

```
fun subscribeClick(topic: String) {

    Log.d(TAG, "topic = $topic")

    try {
        mqttManager?.subscribeToTopic(topic, AWSIotMqttQos.QOS0,
            { topic, data ->
                runOnUiThread {
                    try {
                        val message = String(data, Charsets.UTF_8)
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message arrived:")
                        Log.d(TAG, "   Topic: $topic")
                        Log.d(TAG, " Message: $message")

                        val gson = Gson()
                        val notificationModel = gson.fromJson(message, NotificationModel::class.java)
                        var orderServiceMapperResponseModel = OrderServiceMapperResponseModel()
                        orderServiceMapperResponseModel.seatId = notificationModel.seatId
                        orderServiceMapperResponseModel.serviceName = notificationModel.service
                        orderServiceMapperResponseModel.id = notificationModel.id
                        orderServiceMapperResponseModel.createdDate = notificationModel.createdDate
                        serviceList.add(orderServiceMapperResponseModel)
                        if (isPictureInPictureMode) {
                            if (isShownNotification) {
                                updateNotificationCount()
                            } else {
                                updatePIPWindowContent()
                            }
                        } else {
                            updateAdapterDataSource()
                        }

                    } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Message encoding error.", e)
                    }
                }
            })
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Subscription error.", e)
    }
}
```

I'm also always making disconnect() request inside onDestroy() of my app screen

```
mqttManager?.disconnect()
```

But Still I'm getting 3 subscription messages instead of 1.

Comment: The short answer to the title is, it can't unless it keeps track of it for its self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive 3 duplicated messages not because you subscribe 3 times but *because you create 3 individual connections*.

The [MQTT specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718067) clearly states that

> If a Server receives a SUBSCRIBE Packet containing a Topic Filter that is identical to an existing Subscription’s Topic Filter then it MUST completely replace that existing Subscription with a new Subscription.

meaning duplicated subscriptions per connection never happen, unless the server has a broken implementation.

Your code looks like that it never send disconnect requests while a new connection is created whenever the code block is invoked.

You should keep a single MQTT session, or make sure you close the connection when the app is closed.

Comment: Many Thanks for the reply.I have incorporated all the suggestions you have mentioned here but I'm still facing the same issue.I have updated my post above ,added subscription and connection code snippet. Please have a look if you could really help more here.

Comment: @priyadhingra19 1. I have no idea what API you are using, specifically what instance the `mqttManager` is? 2. You should check connection first before calling `connect()` 3. Consider using `onPause()` or `onStop()` instead of `onDestory()`.

Comment: It worked now. I found the issue it was at server end ,server was making multiple connection .I have fixed that it is working perfectly now. Many Thanks for the quick help

Comment: @priyadhingra19 No problem. It's weird that the server makes multiple connections though. Please consider upvote and marking the answer if it helps :)